# How to await I/O blocking call that doesn't follow any async pattern

Tags: .net, async-await

In every exposition I've seen of using async/await for I/O blocking calls, in the end there is either a dummy call (Task.Delay) or an API that supports *some* async pattern. But what if you have an API has I/O blocking methods, but doesn't provide anything you can await on or wrap in some way so that you can await on it? I understand that TaskCompletionSource is supposed to be the way to deal with this, but I haven't yet found anything that really explains (to me anyway) how it works. I have tried

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<SomeType>();
try
{
  tcs.SetResult(IoBlockingCall());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  tcs.SetException(ex);
}
return tcs.Task;
```

The above code does not work as I expect in the sense of returning immediately after tcs.SetResult(). Clearly I'm missing something, but I haven't found an example of how to do this that doesn't rely on you *already* having a method that returns immediately after initiating some I/O blocking op. I guess a simpler way of asking the same question would be, if I had to write e.g. SqlConnection.OpenAsync, how would I do it?

(Note, please don't answer with Task.Run(). This is about I/O blocking, not offloading. Thanks!)

For the other commenters, what I was trying to accomplish here was specifically *not* starting up another thread. That would be trivial to do, but would defeat what the primary purpose of async/await is wrt I/O blocking. (See [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)). This made me think that it would likely be impossible without breaking through bottom of .NET, and according to @PetSerAl that's the case.

Comment: Then you do not under stand the purpose of [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.7.1) , `Task.Run` and also I/O blocking. Read [The Nature of `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/06/02/the-nature-of-taskcompletionsourcetresult/)

Comment: Throw the blocking call onto another thread and use the tcs to signal what happens.

Comment: If call is blocking, then it need a thread. No other way to keep current thread free except for offload blocking call to different thread.

Comment: *Clearly I'm missing something, but I haven't found an example of how to do this that doesn't rely on you already having a method that returns immediately after initiating some I/O blocking op.* It is simply impossible. Method should be asynchronous starting from OS kernel call, otherwise it will need to use thread somewhere to host that synchronous OS kernel call.

Comment: When Microsoft designed `System.IO` there was no async/await, so the API surface was ugly and could not be easily used. You might try to use the latest `System.IO.Pipelines.*` namespaces, https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/tree/master/src

Comment: @PetSerAl: Yeah, I figured it was either I don't understand or impossible. The impossibility must be obvious to experts that I've read, so they don't even address it. (I was going to re-title the post "Turtles all the way down." ;-)

Answer (score -3):

That's chat [`Task.Yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield) is for.

You can try this:

```
Task.Yield();
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<SomeType>();
try
{
  tcs.SetResult(IoBlockingCall());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  tcs.SetException(ex);
}
return tcs.Task;
```

But that might not work as you expected (read the **Remarks** section on the documentation). In some cases `Task.Delay(0)` will be more effective.

Because `IoBlockingCall` is blocking, for most intents and purposes you'll need to offload it. Or not, like in ASP.NET where there's no benefit in offloading.